# How do I switch between Player and Model joystick inputs in a regular interval?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I'm currently working on a machine learning model (in Python with Keras and Tensorflow) that can drive by itself in Need for Speed Most Wanted 2005. I recorded a couple of hours of me driving in the game and fed it to the model. I was able to get the inputs of the model to the game with vjoy via its "vJoyInterface.dll" file. So that works fine.

Now, the model is of course not perfect and the data that I recorded is mostly of me just driving normally through the streets. When the model is driving on its own it quickly gets itself into situations for which there are hardly any training samples in the training data.

Inspired by the solution in [this video](https://youtu.be/Ipi40cb_RsI?t=266), where he faced the same problem, I wanted to try to switch between the player and the model being in charge while collecting data.

But it turned out to be much more difficult for me than expected. Here are various things I have tried or thought about doing:

- Using Joystick Gremlin to forward either the steering wheel or the model inputs. (Couldn't access the same device from two places)
- Create two vjoy devices (NFSMW can't see any devices if there is more than one vjoy device)
- Hide second vjoy device with HidGuardian (But apparently you can't hide a vjoy device.)
- Running the model as a plugin in Joystick Gremlin (Maybe possible, but I don't know how to access an environment or if all the existing code works within the plugin)

Nothing worked out and I'm close to just giving up this idea. But before I do that, I wanted to see if anyone else knows a way to do this.

PS: It's my first time posting. I hope everything is clear. Let me know if anything is missing.